# wcf return response to client from a different thread with out Duplex

Tags: c#, wcf

when invoking a service operation asynchronously:

```
proxy.OperationCompleted += new EventHandler<OperationEventArgs>(OperationCallback);
proxy.OperationAsync(OperationRequest request);
```

on the server side :

```
 new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunOperations)).Start();

 public OperationResponse Operation(OperationRequest request)
 {
      Queue.Enqueue(request); 
 }

 // in some other thread  
 public OperationResponse RunOperations()
 {
     OperationRequest request = Queue.Dequeue();
     OperationResponse response = Execute(request);
     // here i need to some how return to response to the threw the channel 
     // which sent the request 
 }
```

my question :

is there a way with out constructing a duplex channel and returning the response via callback , to reference the submitting channel and return a response threw it ?

Answer (score 2):

WCF has its own threading model. By default the operation is processed synchronously by calling your operation contract - when the call to operation contract ends the call itself ends as well and response is returned to the client. If you spawn a thread in your operation call you must wait for thread to complete (block the operation thread) to return the response. It can result in throughput problems because you can have all threads from thread pool blocked by waiting calls and there will be no thread to serve new requests.

As alternative WCF provides two additional mechanisms: [asynchronous services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and duplex services. In asynchronous services you get a thread from thread pool to server the initial requests where some asynchronous I/O operation is executed. When the I/O execution begins the the operation's thread is returned to thread pool to serve other requests. Once the I/O is completed the operation is assigned to a new thread from thread pool and end method is called. Still the operation itself and WCF processing model handles the response - you cannot fork threads manually and return the response from different thread. This can greatly improve throughput in some kind of operations.

When none of these models suits your needs you need duplex services where you can call back to client whenever you need.

In all scenarios you have to deal with some problems related to channel timeouts.